# Relay QueryRenderer fragmentContainer passed props different from server response because id conflict

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs, relay, relaymodern

I'm having this weird issue, basically:

1. graphql request made from `QueryRenderer`
2. Response comes back from the server contains data (inspected from Network tab in dev tools)
3. `props` populated in `QueryRenderer` `render({ error, props })` function
4. the `props` get passed down into child component with `createFragmentContainer` which renders the value
5. The rendered value for **one field is different** from the response

I'm not sure what relay is doing when it is looking up the data from its own store, but I suspect it is because missing `id` declaration in a type, here is the code examples:

App.js

```
<QueryRenderer
  environment={env}
  query={graphql`
    query ScoreboardContainerQuery($ID: ID!) {
      scoreboard(id: $ID) {
        ...Scoreboard_scoreboard
      }
    }
  `}
  variables={{ID: gameID}}

  render={({ error, props }) => {
    return <Scoreboard scoreboard={props ? props.scoreboard : undefined} />
  }}
/>
```

Scoreboard.js

```
const Scoreboard = ({ scoreboard }) => (
  <main>
    {scoreboard.matches.map(match => <Match key={match.id} match={match} />)}
  </main>
)

export default createFragmentContainer(Scoreboard, {
  scoreboard: graphql`
  fragment Scoreboard_scoreboard on FootballScoreboard {
    matches {
      ...Match_match
    }
  }
  `,
})
```

Match.js

```
const Match = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <div>
      {match.homeTeam.displayName}-
      {match.homeTeam.score}
    </div>
    <div>
      {match.awayTeam.displayName}-
      {match.awayTeam.score}
    </div>
  </div>
)

export default createFragmentContainer(Match, {
  match: graphql`
    fragment Match_match on Match {
      date
      homeTeam { // this is a Team type
        id
        displayName
        score
      }
      awayTeam { // this is a Team type
        id
        displayName
        score
      }
    }
  `,
})
```

sample response for `matches` from server:

```
matches = [
  {
    "date": "2017-09-03T06:00:00Z",
    "homeTeam": {
      "id": "330",
      "displayName": "STG",
      "score": "20"
    },
    "awayTeam": {
      "id": "332",
      "displayName": "CBY",
      "score": "0"
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-08-27T06:00:00Z",
    "homeTeam": {
      "id": "329",
      "displayName": "PEN",
      "score": "14"
    },
    "awayTeam": {
      "id": "330",
      "displayName": "STG",
      "score": "0"
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-08-12T05:00:00Z",
    "homeTeam": {
      "id": "330",
      "displayName": "STG",
      "score": "42"
    },
    "awayTeam": {
      "id": "337",
      "displayName": "GCT",
      "score": "0"
    }
  },
]
```

the rendered value:

```
(
  <main>
    <div>
      <div>STG-42</div>
      <div>CBY-6</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>PEN-0</div>
      <div>STG-42</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>STG-42</div>
      <div>GCT-18</div>
    </div>
  </main>
)
```

So all `STG` value is overridden to 42, and it shouldn't be.

Is this issue caused because there is no `id` in the `Match` type which the response is an array? 
and that's why relay is looking for the `Team` with same id?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because Relay updates the `Team` type of id `330` (which is SGT), with the latest value each time ; and the last one of the list is 42.

You could remove the `score` field from the `Team` (it does seem a little bit odd, a team doesn't have **one** score ; it is within a match that she has a score), and create 2 fields on the `Match` type: `awayTeamScore` and `homeTeamScore`.

Comment: yeah realised that relay requires unique ID for each type, so ended up creating unique ID for the teamID combined with matchID

Comment: @andiwin do you mean that the `id` in `homeTeam` and `awayTeam` is now dependant of the match ID, thought it is a Team type ?